# Vue v-for="" :key="" does not work

Tags: vue.js

need some help.
I have this code in App.vue:

```
<template>
...
  <select class="form-control">
    <option v-for="{car, index} in cars" :key="index">
      {{ car.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
...
</template>
```

And this in main.js :

```
const cars = [
  {name: 'ford', model: 'focus'}
]

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cars: cars
  },
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

So it should render an `<option>` item but it doesn't. And i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template code should be like this:

```
<template>
...
  <select class="form-control">
    <option v-for="(car, index) in cars" v-bind:value="index">
      {{ car.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
...
</template>
```

which means if you want to bind a value to your option you need to use `v-bind`.

for more details please check the documentation [select doc vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)

Comment: This leads to error "
[vue/require-v-for-key]
Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives."
Even example in official docs leads to the same error:
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Comment: I think you use vuejs 1.x version. my syntaxe work for vuejs 2.x

Comment: i am using vue cli 3.0.0-beta.11

Comment: Please share with us the Vuejs version that you use in your project not the Vue cli. check package.json file and you will find it

Comment: "vue": "^2.5.11"

Comment: Ok it works, but still with an ESlint error, guess problem in vue version.
Thx everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you're dealing primarily with a syntax error. Your `v-for` should use parentheses, not curly braces, i.e. it should be `v-for="(car, index) in cars"` rather than `v-for="{car, index} in cars"`.

Additionally, I noticed you're using `:key="index"`. If you mean to have the `index` be the value for that particular option, you should be doing `:value="index"`. If using `:key` is intentional, then you might want to consider using a value that isn't `index`, something unique that won't change if the sort order of the array changes. There are legitimate uses for doing `:key="index"`, but I don't believe you're attempting to use it for those purposes.

Comment: Thx for answer.
I want to iterate over may array and add all objects as `<option>` in select. Now there one object (`<option>`), but i want to add 2 more in array.

Comment: add other objects inside your cars array separate by ","

Comment: @ElNegro You only need to add more objects to your array, simple as that. That being said, this is beyond the scope of your original question. Please avoid adding additional scope to it. If your original issue is resolved, you should select an answer. If you still need additional information beyond the scope of the question, you can submit a new one.